# Inline null check for string in vba

Tags: string, vba, null

iam searching a way to check if a string is empty before converting it to date, problem i that i want to avoid `if-else` since i have to use it on multiple variable in single statement:

```
Call MyObj.Insert(CInt(Me.ddlFiltroPD), _
                                    CInt(Me.Parent!ddlFiltroEsito), _
                                    CInt(Nz(ddlFiltroPD.Column(1))), _
                                    Nz(txtPuntoDebolezza, ""), _
                                    CInt(Nz(Me.ddlRilevanza, 0)), _
                                    Nz(txtInterventi, ""), _
                                    Nz(txtOwner, ""), _
                                    CDate(txtData1), _
                                    CDate(txtData2), _
                                    CDate(txtData3), _
                                    CDate(txtData4), _
                                    Nz(txtMotivazioneChiusura) _
            )
```

txtData1, txtData2, txtData3 and txtData4 can be null and i have to convert it to a data when they are not null

i have thought to create a function to do the convertion or to use some temp variables but iam looking for something better

Comment: What is/are `txtData`? - A string primitive variable can never be null, just empty

Comment: They are empty; equal to "" / len 0 - a string in VBA can never be null (only Variants can be Null)

Comment: debug says that textbox is null: nz(txtData1, "test") returns "test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved in this way

```
Call MyObj.Insert(..., _
                      txtData1, _
                      txtData2, _
                      txtData3, _
                      txtData4, _
            )
```

in `MyObj.Insert` i change parameter to variant and i transform parameter using `Format(txtData1, "YYYYMMDD")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
IIf(txtdata1 = vbNullString, "", CDate(txtdata1))
```

Comment: try IIf(IsNull(txtdata1 ), "", CDate(txtdata1 )) but get runtime error 94, "invalid use of null"

Comment: access try to compile cdate and raise error
IIf(IsNull(txtdata1 ), "", CDate("01/01/2016")) returns ""